# Windows "jumping" between monitors when scale plugin used

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, window, window-placement

I have two monitors. I am very particular as to which window goes to which monitor (e.g. Firefox always on the left side; terminals on other workspaces always maximized on the left monitor; R graphics always on the right monitor etc.).

I use the scale plugin with the "initiate window picker for all windows" binding to switch between windows. I also use the option "use device with pointer" of the "place windows" plugin (that way, when opening a window, it goes to the monitor that I want it to go; however, the behavior I'm about to describe happens also when the option "use active device" is selected).

However, often when I use the scale plugin to jump between windows placed on different workspaces, it jumps from one monitor to the other. Most frequently it moves from the monitor on the left hand side to the monitor on the right. It annoys the hell out of me, because I then feel compelled to drag the window back to the left side. It never happens if I do not switch between workspaces.

I think it might be due to the "place windows" options and the "scale" plugin options that I use together. You see, when I initiate window picker for all windows, most of the windows, for some reason, get minimized on the right hand monitor, like this:

[image]

Then when I select one of the windows on the right, the cursor is on the right hand side of the screen; and so maybe the "place window" plugin gets called and puts the window there (because it is both, the active device and the device with the cursor). So here is a before calling window picker and after calling window picker screenshot:

**Before:**

[image]

Then I use window picker to switch to a window on another workspace, and again to switch back to the initial workspace with the firefox window:

**After:**

[image]

**Question:** What can I do to prevent this behavior? I mean, apart from using window picker for all workspaces.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My windows even jump to different workspaces. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion you might try. Launch `Compiz, go to Windows Management, and click on Scale` then click on the `Behaviour` tab.

Check to see what your setting for `"Multi Output Mode"` is. Try setting it to `"On current output device"` and see if that helps any...

[image]

I hope this helps... Good Luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, but no :-( Still the same. However, +1 because it falsifies my hypothesis. Since the window miniatures are now on the left (active) device, as is the pointer, and since the Firefox (or another) window jumps to the *right* (inactive) device when switching to that desktop, it probably doesn't have anything to do with window placement and pointer position.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remedy this by opening General->Display Settings in CCSM and changing "Overlapping Output Handling" to anything other than "Smart".